# Best api service for 3D bin packing algorithm

Tags: library, web-apis

I'm developing an eCommerce which automatically creates shipment with the DHL API. The only problem is that I have to decide in which package/s I have to put the purchased items. So my problem is, given n packages with different width, length and height I have to decide which to use in order to fit all the purchased items which are considered to be parallelepipeds with different width, length and height. Understanding in how many packages the items fit and the size of those is fundamental, cause during the checkout process I have to tell to the customer the shipment costs and to know this price I have to send to DHL the packages with all their specifications, such as number, weight, height etc.

I'm looking around to see if there are reliable API services which I can use to solve this problem. Since I guess is a well known problem and there will be for sure some good solutions on the market, I do not want to spend a lot of time to "reinvent the wheel" and probably come out with a not so well optimised product. So far I found just one free API packit4me but it does not seem to work well and it does not get updates since 2014. Plus, I do not know if it is reliable or not. The alternatives would be to go with a payment service such as 3dbinpacking, which is well done and well documented.

Since is a very new problem for me, I do not know if there are recommended ways to approach this kind of problem. What do other eCommerces do? I do not need a so precise solution, cause at the end a human shipper will pack all the item in a box. So if he finds out that he can use a smaller package he can choose it with no problem. What I would like is to find the best product which can best fit my needs. Maybe I have already found the right one (3dbinpacking), but I do not know if there are other kind of solutions... maybe easier and with no costs.

Do you have any recommendation?

Answer (score 0):

I have created https://bindrake.com as a 3D bin packer. It is free to use up to a certain limit. I also have a custom api if requested.